# Best way to update NULL in records

Tags: sql

I have a table say TA where the data looks like,

| ID | SSN | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | 123 | 1 |
| Null | 123 | 2 |
| Null | 123 | 3 |
| xyzabc | 123 | 4 |

I want to get one value of ID that is not null and update all the other rows based on that value.

What I have come up with:

```
UPDATE TA 
SET ID = (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TA as T1 
          WHERE TA.SSN= T1.SSN AND T1.ID !=NULL)
          WHERE TA.ID=NULL;
```

I wanted to know the most efficient way to do this as I might be performing this on a table with a large number of rows.

Comment: And what happened when you tried that....?

Comment: @Stu. Will try to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

When you need compare with `NULL` you must use `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL` statements

```
UPDATE TA 
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(ID) ID, SSN FROM TA GROUP BY SSN
) TA1 ON TA.SSN = TA1.SSN
SET TA.ID = TA1.ID
WHERE TA.ID IS NULL;
```

[SQL editor online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/53a1461072b65ee1ce9fa975f0e77836/)

The above example for MySQL, when you have another server you need to match the query